# Find Curent date from coloumn 'A' and update curent time in Coloumn 'B' (Excel 2010)

Tags: python, datetime, openpyxl

Could you possibly have a look on below case and help me with excel update.

I want to find the today's date in column A first and then update current time in column B.

Currently i have tried Openpyxl and wrote below code, but no success. 
please help

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\New folder')
import openpyxl, datetime, time
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sandeep1.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('A1')
for cell in ws['A']:
   if cell.value == datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        update ws['B'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

[here is the screen-shot of excel coloumns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQpob.jpg)
any help would be much appreciated.
thanks 
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code, so that it works and also includes some comments.

```
import openpyxl, datetime, time

filename = "TestWorkBook.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename) #Opening up the Workbook
ws = wb["SheetContainingDates"] #Selecting the sheet to work against

ds = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #Todays date
ts = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') #Timestamp from "now"

for cell in ws["A"]: #Loops through all set values in Column A
    if str(ds) in str(cell.value): #Checks if the string-format of ds is in the string-format of cell.value
        ws["B%s" % cell.row] = ts #Sets the neighboring cell to the Timestamp

wb.save(filename) #Saves the workbook after it's done with all the cells.
```

---

If you would like to execute the code on all the available sheets, instead of hard-coding the `sheetname` into the script, just make a loop that goes through all the available sheets for you:

```
import openpyxl, datetime, time

filename = "TestWorkBook.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename) #Opening up the Workbook

ds = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #Todays date
ts = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') #Timestamp from "now"

for sheet in wb.worksheets: #Loops through all the sheets of the Workbook.
    for cell in sheet["A"]: #Loops through all set values in Column A
        if str(ds) in str(cell.value): #Checks if the string-format of ds is in the string-format of cell.value
            sheet["B%s" % cell.row] = ts #Sets the neighboring cell to the Timestamp

wb.save(filename) #Saves the workbook after it's done with all the cells.
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir!. I will be more clear in future. there is one more thing to ask. How to select the date in whole workbook, if workbook has multiple sheets?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I am following what you mean here. Are you asking how to execute the code on multiple sheets? Also, what do you mean with "select the date in whole workbook"?

Comment: yes, I want to execute this code in multiple sheets and update current time based on today's date..

Comment: yes, I want to execute this code in multiple sheets and update current time based on today's date. For example, there are sheets in workbook named, Sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 and sheet4 and every sheet has date mentioned in column and it. So I only want to execute above code to all sheets in one go... Sorry, i was not be clearer earlier.

Comment: I've updated the code with a new version that doesn't target a specific sheet, and just looks through all of the available ones. I've not been able to test it, due to not having Excel available on my current computer, but it should work.

If this has resolved all your questions, please mark the question as answered.